# Correct 'in' operator usage

Tags: delphi

Consider the following procedure

```
procedure InTests;
var
  N, K: Integer;

begin
  N:= 1111;
  if N in [6, 8, 10]          // this is correct, readable and effective code
    then ShowMessage('OK');

  K:= 11;
  if N in [6, 8, 10, K]       // this is correct but less effective
    then ShowMessage('OK');   //  (compiler creates local 16-bytes set var)

  K:= 1111;
  if N in [6, 8, 10, K]       // this is a bug (K > 255)
    then ShowMessage('OK');
end;
```

`in` operator instead of `if` chain

```
  if (N = 6) or (N = 8) or (N = 10)
    then ShowMessage('OK');
```

makes the code more compact and readable, but Delphi documentation is silent about it, and you should be aware of potential problems.

The question is: should the `in` operator usage with constants only in brackets, for example

```
  if N in [6, 8, 10]
    then ShowMessage('OK');
```

be considered a good practice in Delphi?

Comment: Yes, but you are showing literals, not constants. That is, I would have `MEANINGFULNAME = 6;` declared somewhere in a const section and use that in the `in` condition. Using literals is something I would not consider a good practice (hard to search for, and you are likely to miss one when you need to change a value).

Comment: @MarjanVenema You are a true purist programmer :)

Comment: I'll take that as a compliment :) Don't know about purist, just stung a couple of times too many by code using literals...

Comment: just a note: you could use `case` statement to bypass the `set` limitation (`K` should be a constant).

Comment: @kobik Good point, and compiler generates the same effective code.

Comment: When you say the `if` statement "makes the code more compact," you're talking about the compiler-generated machine code, right? The Delphi code is clearly *less* compact than the alternatives shown here. Are there other places where the documentation *isn't* silent about the generated machine code? I don't think so; the documentation talks about the Delphi language at a higher level than the compiler's output.

Answer (score 5):

It is most definitely good practice. It makes the code far more readable and removes the need for logical operators, parentheses and so on. I would always use `in` for such a test.

The only drawback is Delphi's very limited support for [sets](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Sets) (base ordinal type can have no more than 256 values). But where you are not bound by those limitations then you should have no hesitation in using `in`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a `set of byte`. The question you should ask yourself is whether a `set of byte` is truly what your numbers represent? You have "magic numbers" here, and while I understand that it is just a sample, you must consider that while

```
 if Token in [TokenString, TokenNumber, TokenChar] then
```

...would be considered good practice, this:

```
 if N in [2, 12, 14, 19] then
```

...would be not.

However in the first case (named tokens), an explicit set type would be much more good practice:

```
 type TokenSet = ( TokenNone, TokenString, TokenChar,... )
```

Then the first sample is definitively a good practice.

Comment: The question is not about magic numbers at all. I can edit it to remove magic numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't it read "const TokenSet =" instead of "type TokenSet ="?

Comment: @Uwe, no, it's a set type (http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/delphi_set_type.htm)

Comment: It's really not hard to think of cases where set of byte is appropriate.

Comment: @David, I know, however, it's not always the case.

Comment: Kornel, `TokenSet` as defined here is an **enum** type, not a **set** type.